# Get list of video devices and set any one from it as default using c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, camera

hi i have to fetch list of all cameras attached to my pc
and set any selected camera as default.

i followed this link which provides list and also invokes camera but the code does not works all time i mean i get the list but camera is invoked only once and that too after reboot

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/810262008070218AM/8.aspx

also i need to capture yuv video from camera using streaming.

please help.

Comment: I don't think that Windows has a concept of a "default camera".

Comment: but webcam must be the default camera, in my mac which is dual booted with windows i can see the "Apple isight camera" as the default in camera list..

Comment: i always get the driver name not the device friendly name. anybody have any idea

Comment: can someone provide me help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: My point is that Windows doesn't have a default.  Applications might have a default, but Windows doesn't.

Comment: Here's a hint for the future.  Video input devices are often called "capture devices".  2 minutes with a search engine found what I believe is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i follwed this sample and it worked for me:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

Comment: the above codeproject link will work only when camera device connected state. BUT if you want monitor the MIC connected status then this method will fail if camera is not connected to PC.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [SystemDeviceEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407180%28VS.85%29.aspx) object.  [This](http://www.ms-windows.info/Help/enumerate-1394-firewire-devices-7147.aspx) page shows an example of enumerating 1394 devices.